# Error: Returned error: insufficient funds for gas * price + value at Object.ErrorResponse

Tags: solidity, web3js

[image: screenshot of faced issue]
I am using web3 version 1.3.3 and tried to call the contract method using send() but it is showing an error above( Error: Returned error: insufficient funds for gas * price + value at Object.ErrorResponse )

```
const ERC20ListInst = await this.contract;
const res = await ERC20ListInst.methods.tokenToWei(addr, this.web3.utils.toHex(amount)).send({
   from: this.web3.eth.defaultAccount,
   gas: 100000
});
```

I have enough eth on the account and can't sure why this is happening.
Is there anyone has faced this one before?

Comment: Hi, welcome :)
Please don't screenshot errors, but copy and paste it here as text.

Comment: I fixed screenshot issue, please check and let me know if you have any idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was issue on truffle wallet provider url. I was going to use Goerli and there was enough fund but I wrote with mainnet url. So it was checking mainnet account and showing me insufficient balance. After I indicate wallet provider to goerli then it worked. Thanks.